# Facebook.h not found

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am trying to work my way through a Facebook SDK book I got off Amazon. The coding starts with 
`#import "Facebook/Facebook.h"`
And has you create a Facebook object almost immediately. I do not seem to have this file anywhere in my SDK. Is this book outdated already? It was just published last fall...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following is up to date and has been a great resource for me:  [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/)

I use the following import for accessing the Facebook SDK:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

It appears your environment does not have the Facebook framework.  Download that [here.](https://github.com/downloads/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/FacebookSDK-3.1.1.pkg)

***Update***

I have found the offical Facebook answer to this.  Apparently these are deprecated headers that can still be used for backwards compatability.

Note that at the bottom, if Xcode is having problems recognizing the import after you complete the steps below, restart XCode.

> Add the headers by dragging the DeprecatedHeaders folder from the
>   FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/DeprecatedHeaders folder into the
>   Frameworks section of your Project Navigator.
>
> Choose 'Create groups for any added folders' and deselect 'Copy items
>   into destination group's folder (if needed)'. This adds the headers as
>   a reference.
>
> Now, open up your app delegate header file and replace the Facebook
>   framework import with the Facebook header import.
>
> Change:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

> To:

```
 #import "Facebook.h"
```

> This allows you to make call to the FBDialog classes. The Facebook.h
>   header includes the
>    header files.
>
> Note: If you have any problems with Xcode recognizing the Facebook.h
>   file, just close and reopen your Xcode project.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/)

Comment: Hi, again, thanks for the comment!  I have the SDK (version 3.1) downloaded and installed, and am now able to get some stuff working with my project. What I am hoping to determine is if the book I bought is using a class that has been deprecated in 3.1. I will check out your link. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes, I see your link is one I am already familiar with. Could you comment on the actual file named facebook.h?  It seems like everything has moved almost exclusively to the use of the FBSession class. Is this correct?

Comment: You can retrieve the active session with the FBSession class simply by FBSession.activeSession.  Facebook.h is now a deprecated header from my understanding.  You should not be trying to pull this in.

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1**:
  Select Blue icon vidhyasalai as shown in screenshot 1.

**Step 2:** 
Select `Targets-> vidhyasalai -> build settings - > Search paths` (if you can’t find search path, use search tap to search)

**Step 3:** 
select Serch paths->Framework search paths

**Step 4:**
select and press return(enter)key

**Step 5:**
Now remove `$(PROJECT_DIR)` and press return(enter) key.Now it will be empty also expand and check for debug,adhoc and release,make sure all will be empty.

**Step 6:** Repeat 5,6,7 of screenshot steps for this target second icon,expand and check for debug,adhoc and release,make sure all will be empty.

**Step 7:**
Right click framework,delete and select move to trash

**Step 8:**
Again Drag and drop attached framework in this mail you will get screen like screenshot 2, make sure “destination” as select the given radio button as per screen shot ref

**Step 9:**

Drag framework to the location under framework folder. Clean and build. Hope error was cleared

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This book is not outdated. May be you added framework as cocoapods?

Then to find this file in project you should write:

```
#import <Facebook-iOS-SDK/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

Then just hold 'Command' button and press on it and you will get to it location

Answer (score 2):

You need to download and install the SDK and after that add the Facebokk framework to your project.

Once you're done with that part you will be able to import FacebookSDK.

heres' the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/

watch the video

Comment: HI there, thanks for the comment!  In fact I did already download the 3.1 version of the SDK and install it.  After failing to get the facebook.h header to import I went through some of the tutorials in the dev.fb page, and I was able to log a user in, etc.  I am just wondering about the fate of the actual class Facebook.h?